# Validator using awk [:alnum:] regular expression group not working as intended

Tags: csv, awk

I'm currently coding a CSV validator using awk. Here's an example of the code:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NF!=17{print "not enough fields"; exit}
!($1~/[[:alnum:]]$/) {print "1st field invalid"; exit}' npp_test.cs
```

However the `alnum` section won't accept both alphabetic and numerical characters.

So if the data is "t" the program will exit, and if the data is "1" the same thing. However if it is "t1" it won't recognise it as valid.
How would I go about getting the code to accept a mix of alpha and numeric data.

Also the top line isn't really relevant as its just field count:)

Comment: Try `awk '!($1~/[[:alnum:]]$/) {print "1st field invalid"; exit}' <<< "t"` and then with `"1"`, `"t1"` and `"..."` instead of `"t"`. You should get the wanted behavior... at least it works as expected on my system `:)`.

Comment: thanks for the reply but I'm getting a unexpected redirection, and also wouldn't that only work for a t?

Comment: The unexpected redirection error means you're not using Bash... ok, not a big deal, do this instead: `echo "t" | awk '!($1~/[[:alnum:]]$/) {print "1st field invalid"; exit}'`. Your regexp tests whether the first field ends with an alphanumerical value... so it will accept `t`, `1`, `t1`, but not `...`.

Comment: however it did  bring the cause of the problem to my attention thank you it was a stray ^ in my code :)

Comment: i do have a follow question though is there a variation of "alnum" to allow only uppercase

Comment: To get uppercase `[:alnum:]`... well, just use `($1~/[[:upper:][:digit:]]$/)` (that is, _uppercase_ or _digit_).

Comment: ye for some reason it's still accepting lowercase

Comment: I doubt it... `echo "t" | awk '!($1~/[[:upper:][:digit:]]$/) {print "1st field invalid"; exit}'` should be rejected.

Comment: @jordanb111 if you have a question then post a [mcve] containing concise, testable sample input and expected output plus the minilam code required to reproduce your problem. Right now you're doing a lot of hand-waving and showing us code that isn't what you're actually running (re: `it was a stray ^ in my code` when trhere is no `^` in the code you posted) so it's very hard for us to help you.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this task? If not, please provide a string or two you test against and state the expected behavior. If you need to check if the input is only upper/digit, use `!($1 ~ /^[[:upper:][:digit:]]+$/)` or `!($1 ~ /^[[:upper:][:digit:]]*$/)`.

Comment: yes I managed to solve it by not using posix and instead used [A-Z0-9]{1,25}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your environment does not support POSIX character classes in `awk` you may use explicit character ranges in bracket expressions:

```
!($1 ~ /^[A-Z0-9]{1,25}$/)
```

Here,

- `^` - matches the start of a line
- `[A-Z0-9]{1,25}` - matches 1 to 25 uppercase letters or digits
- `$` - end of string.

NOTE: To avoid any issues with collations, you may add `LANG=C` before the `awk` command.